# Passing form data to API custom route with WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, routes, wordpress-rest-api

Getting the following 500 code response when making my API call: `PUT https://my-site.com/wp/wp-json/contact/v1/send 500`

In `functions.php` my WP custom route is defined thus:

```
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', 'send', array(
    'methods' => 'PUT',
    'callback' => 'sendContactMail'
  ));
});
```

Here's how I'm making my API call:

```
formData.append('contact_name', this.contactName)
formData.append('contact_email', this.contactEmail)
formData.append('contact_message', this.contactMessage)

this.$axios.$put('https://my-site.com/wp/wp-json/contact/v1/send', formData)
  .then((res) => {
    this.ApiResponse = res
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.$toast.error(err.response)
  })
```

Why am I getting a 500 error?

Comment: do you have access to server logs? WP error logs?

Comment: What happens if, instead of `https://my-site.com/wp/wp-json/contact/v1/send` you call `https://my-site.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send` (without the /wp/ folder)? Do you have any .htaccess redirects or similar?

Comment: Open this link (https://my-site.com/wp/wp-json)  in the browser and make sure the `contact/v1` is in the namespace.

Comment: timur I have access to web server log, there's no error when submitting contact form. JP.Aulet I get a 404 if I do that. SagarBahadurTamang it is, https://www.my-site.com/wp/wp-json/contact/v1 works fine

Comment: @drake035, your code seems fine, so it's probably your callback (`sendContactMail()`) which causes the *internal server error* (with status code 500). Try something like `function sendContactMail() { return array( 'foo' => 'bar' ); }` for testing purposes - do you still get the error 500? Try also [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and check for any relevant errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that the callback function is expecting a `return` value. At the end of your `function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) { }` you'll want to [return a `WP_REST_Response` or `WP_Error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value) to send a response back.

I've set up a quick little example here: https://xhynk.com/content-mask/65451758-answer/

The "Click Me (Bad)" and "Click Me (Good)" buttons do exactly the same thing, except change the data being sent. The only difference in the `sendContactMail()` function is like follows:

```
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  if( $request->get_body() == 'return=true' ){
    return new WP_REST_Response(
      array(
        'status' => 200,
        'response' => 'Did the thing'
      );
    );
  }
}
```

The "true" condition only fires when the "Good" button is clicked, which is where the `.done()` block is handled, vs the "Bad" button triggering the `.catch` block.

So you should be able to solve your problem, by doing X, Y, Z with your data, and making sure you're returning a proper response

*Also make sure that you're not running into a PHP error (like directly accessing the `$request` properties, since they're `protected` properties, and doing something like `if( $request->body == 'something' )` will trigger a "PHP Fatal error: Cannot access protected property"* and serve up a 500 error.

Comment: It's true that the endpoint callback should return something, but I don't think that's the problem. And actually, the REST API handbook [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value), "*As of WordPress 5.5, a `_doing_it_wrong` notice is issued if the `wp_send_json()` family of functions is used during a REST API request.*". So one would just return a value which will then be automatically JSON-encoded.

Comment: Good catch on the `wp_send_json()`, looks like I've actually got some code to update myself! Not returning something would always trigger the catch block for me, and of course triggering a fatal error in the function would as well. The only way I was able to reproduce similar issues to the OP was to not return a value at all, or do something illegal like access a protected property/undefined function.

Comment: "Not returning something would always trigger the catch block for me" - I think if you try with Axios than [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://xhynk.com/content-mask/wp-content/themes/studio-pro/assets/scripts/65451758.js), that wouldn't happen. You can try returning nothing and [test it here](https://reqbin.com/ikbtbu1p).. :)

Comment: So actually `if($request->get_body() == 'return=true')` is never true in my case, any idea why? But if I remove this condition it does work. The problem was my return: `return json_decode(json_encode($response));` That line caused the error, replacing it with your return `return new WP_REST_Response(...` fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: The `if($request->get_body() == 'return=true')` is the data that my example was passing only (to help differentiate the "good" button and the "bad" button, one that returns a response and one that doesn't. Glad to help though!

Answer (score 0):

Update function like this

```php
function sendContactMail(WP_REST_Request $request) {
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', '/send', array(
    'methods' => 'PUT',
    'callback' => 'sendContactMail'
  ));
});
```

Update function like this

```php
formData.append('contact_name', this.contactName)
formData.append('contact_email', this.contactEmail)
formData.append('contact_message', this.contactMessage)

this.$axios.$put('https://my-site.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send', formData)
  .then((res) => {
    this.ApiResponse = res
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.$toast.error(err.response)
  })
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The **Bug** is in the **making my API call** JS script
so, remove the extra **wp** from the URL, and than the update URL will look like
https://my-site.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send

The updated script will look like the following

```
formData.append('contact_name', this.contactName)
formData.append('contact_email', this.contactEmail)
formData.append('contact_message', this.contactMessage)

this.$axios.$put('https://my-site.com/wp-json/contact/v1/send', formData)
 .then((res) => {
 this.ApiResponse = res
})
.catch((err) => {
 this.$toast.error(err.response)
});
```